# ROS2 Control Argument not available

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to run ROS 2 Rolling on Ubuntu 22.04. I'm building the Debian Package via `sudo apt install ros-rolling-desktop`. The installation process is fine, but after sourcing the installation, there is no control package so it's not possible to run e.g. `ros2 control list_controllers`.

Output is the following:

```
ros2 control list_controllers
usage: ros2 [-h] [--use-python-default-buffering]
            Call `ros2 <command> -h` for more detailed usage. ...
ros2: error: argument Call `ros2 <command> -h` for more detailed usage.: invalid choice: 'control' (choose from 'action', 'bag', 'component', 'daemon', 'doctor', 'extension_points', 'extensions', 'interface', 'launch', 'lifecycle', 'multicast', 'node', 'param', 'pkg', 'run', 'security', 'service', 'topic', 'wtf')

ROS_VERSION=2
ROS_PYTHON_VERSION=3
ROS_LOCALHOST_ONLY=0
ROS_DISTRO=rolling
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/406981/ros2-control-argument-not-available/) by [dnhrtmn](https://answers.ros.org/users/118703/dnhrtmn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-09-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think I am missing your *question*, but for reference, this is to be expected if all you did was install `ros-rolling-desktop`. The `ros-DISTRO-desktop` installation does not include `ros2_control` - it includes core ROS packages, some tutorials, and some tools. You can see exactly what gets installed with `apt info ros-rolling-desktop`.

`ros2_control` and `ros2_controllers` are considered too application specific to be included with the desktop installation. That being said, they are very easily installed with `sudo apt install ros-rolling-ros2-control ros-rolling-ros2-controllers`

---

Originally posted by [shonigmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/69938/shonigmann/) with karma: 1567 on 2022-09-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dnhrtmn](https://answers.ros.org/users/118703/dnhrtmn/) on 2022-09-26**:
Well, that was quiet easy but solved a lot of problems. Thank you so much for your time and help. :-)

**Comment by [shonigmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/69938/shonigmann/) on 2022-09-26**:
always nice when it's an easy fix right? :)